# Google script to add multiple students to a class in Google Classroom

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-classroom

I have searched, but could not find an answer for how to add multiple students to a class in Google Classroom. I need to add many students at once through an array, but cannot find how to use the array to add the students, given that the Classroom API command only allows me to put one in at a time, and as a result, only grabs the last email in the array within column A in the spreadsheet. How can I add the entire array at once? What I have up to now is the following:

```
 function addStudents () {
 var st = [];
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var lr = ss.getLastRow();
 var a = ss.getRange(1, 1, lr, 1).getValues();
 st.push(a);
 Classroom.Courses.Students.create({userId: st,}, course.id);
       // If userId is singular, how do I add the array?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Classroom API doesn't include an specific method to directly add students to a course in bulk. The available method adds one student by time, so should choose a way to apply this method to each member of the array.

One alternative is to use a for loop, but also it's possible to use JavaScript array methods like [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Example:

Please note that getValues() return a 2D array, so first we should flatten the array of students.

```js
var a = [['Ana'],['Bob']]; // 2D Array
var b = [].concat.apply([], a); // flattened array
b.forEach(function(st){
  console.info(st);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not available method to do that and as Ruben said you'll have to use a loop method... the only thing wrong with that is that Google has a limitation of 1,200 request in a minute. I'm dealing with that limitation 'cause I have to add and remove students from courses. So a loop with a timer for each request will do the trick whenever the number increases.

Right now every student has 4 courses that on a period of time needs to be removed from 4 courses and be added to other 4. Having 150 students I reach the limitation of 1,200 requests... except sometimes the student has 6, 2, 10 courses. With a simple delay of 5 seconds on each request... it will do the trick.

Still hope that Google added a method to accept an array for removing and adding students to courses.